# Laravel retorna vistas equivocadas y en blanco

Tags: laravel

cuando hago click en el enlace que me debería mostrar el index me muestra otra vista, en este caso  la vista SeleccionarColeccion
estas son las rutas que utilizo:

```
Route::resource('intercambios','IntercambiosController');

Route::get('intercambios','IntercambiosController@seleccionarColeccion')->name('intercambios.seleccionarColeccion');
```

esto es lo que hay en el controlador

```
public function index()
{
    $datos['intercambios']=intercambios::paginate(5);
    return view('intercambios.index',$datos);
}

public function seleccionarColeccion(){
    $id=auth()->user()->usu_id;
    $datos['colecciones']=colecciones::where('usu_id','=',$id)->paginate(5);

    return view('intercambios.seleccionarColeccion',$datos);
}
```

Ahora si solo dejo esta ruta:

```
Route::resource('intercambios','IntercambiosController');
```

cuando selecciono el enlace del index me muestra el index correcto, pero cuando le doy al enlace para mostrar seleccionarColeccion me muestra la vista en blanco

este es el enlace en el index hacia seleccionarColeccion

```
<a href="{{url('intercambios/seleccionarColeccion')}}" class="btn btn-success">Nuevo Intercambio</a>
```

¿Como puedo solucionar este error para mostrar ambas vistas?

Comment: Intetenta con ` {{ route('intercambios.seleccionarColeccion') }}` o en su defecto cambia de lugar el resource abajo de este `Route::get('intercambios','IntercambiosController@seleccionarColeccion')->name('intercambios.seleccionarColeccion');
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tenés 2 problemas:

1. Si tenés que agregar rutas extras a un *resource controller*, tenés que declararlas antes, no después. [Documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#restful-supplementing-resource-controllers).
2. Al definir un *resource controller* para *intercambios* se crea -entre otras rutas- la ruta `https://tusitio.com/intercambios`. Esa ruta apunta al mismo lado que la que definís con `Route::get('intercambios','IntercambiosController@seleccionarColeccion')`. Es decir, tenés 2 rutas iguales.

Como recomendación, ejecutá un `php artisan route:list`, eso te devuelve un listado completo de las rutas que tenés definidas. Es útil para ver realmente que estás creando.

Entonces, invertí el orden y cambiá la URL de *seleccionarColeccion*.

```php
Route::get('intercambios/seleccionarColeccion', 'IntercambiosController@seleccionarColeccion')->name('intercambios.seleccionarColeccion');

Route::resource('intercambios', 'IntercambiosController');
```

Por último, como bien te recomienda @BetaM, te conviene utilizar el helper [`route()`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-route) si estás utilizando rutas con nombres.

```php
<a href="{{ route('intercambios.seleccionarColeccion') }}" class="btn btn-success">Nuevo Intercambio</a>
```

---

Ahora, si esa URL la estás definiendo para *crear* un elemento nuevo, deberías utilizar las URLs que ya te define el [resource controller](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers#resource-controllers).

Answer (score 1):

Los controladores de tipo *resource* en Laravel generan un controlador con los siguientes métodos:

- index
- create
- store
- show
- edit
- update
- destroy

Además de lo anterior, cuando compones una ruta de esta forma:

```
Route::resource('/url', 'Controlador');
```

Cada uno de los métodos podrá ser invocado por el nombre cuya composición será de este modo:

```
url.metodo
```

Teniendo esto en claro, podemos observar un problema:

La ruta declarada con `get()` esta nombrada al final con: **`intercambios.seleccionarColeccion`** empata en nombre con la ruta que nos entrega el `resource` y la anula.

Por otro lado dado que ambas rutas apuntan al mismo método y al mismo controlador entonces esta demás tener ambas y como la primera nos ofrece la funcionalidad de la segunda entonces podemos proscindir de esta, quedando solo de esta forma:

```
Route::resource('url', 'Controlador');
```

Además como ya mencioné, este tipo de controlador nombre a todas las rutas quedando de esta forma:

- url.index
- url.create
- url.store
- url.show
- url.edit
- url.update
- utl.destroy

Entonces es una mejor opción usar el helper [Helper route](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-route) en tus vistas donde las llamadas a las URLs quedarían así:

Por ejemplo para mostrar el formulario donde crearemos un nuevo intercambio:

```
<a href="{{ route('intercambios.create')}}" class="btn btn-success">Nuevo Intercambio</a>
```